# GCp Routing through squid Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have multiple vms in one network .All the vms have private ip address and a cloud nat to support egress traffic.

I have installed squid proxy in one of the vms to filter web traffic.

I have added a route with source 0.0.0.0/0 and next hop is my squid VM.

but none of my vms cant access internet.

i am trying to acheive this. vm-> squidVM->NAT->Internetgateway

I was expecting the traffic will route from squid to Nat which is not happening.

Comment: Your question has no details on what you configured or the debugging steps you tried to solve the problem. As written, we can only guess what you did and the problem. Start by reading this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to create good questions. Review this tutorial on setting up Squid in GCP: https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-a-secure-web-proxy-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp-with-squid-proxy-and-clamav-65966eb2058c

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the feedback. As per the link you shared I have to manually provide the squid ip during  each and every request curl --proxy http://$LOAD_BALANCER_IP:3128 https://www.google.com  . I have 20 vms and I am looking at a solution using GCP Routing . I have added a route for 0.0.0.0/0 as next hop I gave my squid VM.But the traffic is not routing from squid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.